# Bash: SPACE-triggered completion

Tags: bash, terminal, bash-completion

In bash, I would like to achieve the following workflow (prompt shown in brackets, `_` is the cursor):

1. Type "foo" (`$ foo_`)
2. Press space. At this point:

   - if foo is a function, say `function foo() { printf "hello from foo" }`

     1. space is printed (`$ foo _`)
     2. the function is called and `hello from foo` is printed after a space - no newline (`$ foo hello from foo_`)
   - if foo is not a function, space is printed and that's it (`$ foo _`)

I have tried:

- Making space send `0x0a` (return) to the terminal emulator (iTerm2 on Mac). This works except it obviously prints the newline character as well
- Using the built-in complete function: `complete -F foo -o nospace foo`. This works but I have to type `foo` then `SPACE` then `TAB` for `hello from foo` to be printed inline
- I have heard you could somehow embed a `\n`-eating script into `PS1`. Really don't know how to get started on that one.

I could also trap a shortcut, such as `Ctrl+T`, to execute foo - but I'd really like to only press `SPACE`.

Ideally space would behave like this only for the first word being typed into the terminal. Any help would be appreciated, please save my sanity.

Why in the world I need this: (I'm a geek AND) I've got an emacs-like ido script that I'd like to be invoked when I type `cd` followed by `SPACE`.

Comment: You can abuse `edit-and-execute-command` and overload `$VISUAL`. Then press `<C-x><C-e>` or rebind `<space>` to run it. Would not recommend.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is using -n 1 with read. For example:

```
foo(){
  echo hello from foo
}

string=''
while read -n 1 a ; do
  if [ "$a" = "" ] ; then
        tpe=`type -t $string`
        if [ "$tpe" = "function" ] ; then
              $string
        fi
        string=''
  else
        string="$string$a"
  fi
done
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. Is there a way  of having other special keys work while inside the loop? For instance, <backspace> to remove a character.

Comment: Instead of the if [ "$a" = "" ], you could do a case statement. You have to try how that works out with special characters.